# Can't get MySQL source query to work using Python mysqldb module

Tags: python, mysql, scripting

I have the following lines of code:

```
sql = "source C:\\My Dropbox\\workspace\\projects\\hosted_inv\\create_site_db.sql"
cursor.execute (sql)
```

When I execute my program, I get the following error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source C:\My Dropbox\workspace\projects\hosted_inv\create_site_db.sql' at line 1

Now I can copy and past the following into mysql as a query:

```
source C:\\My Dropbox\\workspace\\projects\\hosted_inv\\create_site_db.sql
```

And it works perfect.  When I check the query log for the query executed by my script, it shows that my query was the following:

```
source C:\\My Dropbox\\workspace\\projects\\hosted_inv\\create_site_db.sql
```

However, when I manually paste it in and execute, the entire create_site_db.sql gets expanded in the query log and it shows all the sql queries in that file.

Am I missing something here on how mysqldb does queries?  Am I running into a limitation.  My goal is to run a sql script to create the schema structure, but I don't want to have to call mysql in a shell process to source the sql file.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others said, you cannot use the command `source` in MySQLdb Python API

So, instead of running that, load the file and execute it

Lets say your .sql file has

```
create database test;
```

Read the content like

```
sql=open("test.sql").read()
```

And then execute it

```
cursor.execute(sql);
```

You will get new database "test"

Comment: Thanks so much!  sql=open("test.sql").read() does exactly what I want.  I wanted to avoid forking a shell process because it not only felt unnecessary, but then I would have a dependency on the mysql client binaries being installed on the system I executed from.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 8):

The `source` command is one of the [built-in commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html) recognized only by the mysql command-line client.  It is not supported as a statement you can execute via any API.

Some people think you can simply split an SQL script file on the "`;`" statement terminator and call `execute()` on each line you get.  But there are numerous exception cases:

- Statements that are [built-in commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) like `CONNECT`, `SOURCE`, `CHARSET`, `WARNINGS`, `QUIT`, etc.
- Note that built-in commands don't need to terminate in `;` for example `DELIMITER`.
- Statements that contain `;` but not as a terminator, like `CREATE TRIGGER`.
- Statements that contain `;` inside string literals or comments or even quoted identifiers.
- Comments lines.

To load an SQL script programmatically, you'd have to duplicate a fair amount of the functionality of the mysql client.  So it's best if you just fork a process to actually execute that client program with the script as input.

See also:

- [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php/149456#149456)
- [is it possible to call a sql script from a stored procedure in another sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547915/is-it-possible-to-call-a-sql-script-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-sql-script/548119#548119)
- [composing multiple mysql scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080523/composing-multiple-mysql-scripts/1083347#1083347)
- [Running Database scripts in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270476/running-database-scripts/1270629#1270629)

Answer (score 3):

'source' is not an SQL command, but an internal command of the mysql command line client.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem!

As a solution I installed the library [sqlparse](http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/) and used the sqlparse.split( sql ) results. I had to check that sql_parts don't include blank lines as solo statements... Otherwise "WOW" sqlparse is pretty great and exactly what I needed!

```
import sqlparse 
....
sql = open("test.sql").read()
sql_parts = sqlparse.split( sql )
for sql_part in sql_parts:
    if sql_part.strip() ==  '':
        continue 
    cursor.execute( sql_part )
```

FYI: If you do not **run each statement on its own** you may get the error "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now". I only got this error after I added some more queries to my sql file - not the first time around.

Comment: isn't sql_part.strip() enough instead of the replace bit ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose strip would be better and more portable (updated post).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "source" command is specific to the mysql shell executable - it is not an sql command and cannot be interpreted correctly when executed as an sql statement.

To achieve your goal, you probably need to read your script file and parse it into individual sql statements, then execute them one at a time with your cursor.