# Source large MySQL dump with Python script

Tags: python, database-backups, mysql-python

I have a huge (1GB+) database dump that I want to load into new databases on other servers. I tried parsing it line by line and executing each into mysql, but it unfortunately doesn't split lines evenly into commands and just fails on the incomplete ones.

```
filename='/var/test.sql'
fp = open(filename)
while True:
        a = fp.readline()
        if not a:
           break
        cursor.execute(a) #fails most of the time
```

It is also way too large to load the entire thing into memory call that. Furthermore, the [python MySQLdb module](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) does not support [the source command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932298/cant-get-mysql-source-query-to-work-using-python-mysqldb-module).

EDITED

File includes a bunch of insert and create statements. Where its failing is on the inserts of large tables that contain raw text. There are all sorts of semi-colons and newlines in the raw text so hard to split commands based on that.

Comment: It may help if you provide sample code from test.sql.

Comment: Please translate "huge" into megabytes. Please show what test.sql looks like.

Comment: huge is around 1GB, but could theoretically be 5GB, 10GB

Comment: A quick silly question: Doesn't mySQL supply an executable program that will do bulk create and insert statements from your file (presumably a lot faster than a Python script that parsed your file and did it a statement at a time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't spawn out a process to do it for you?

```
import subprocess

fd = open(filename, 'r')
subprocess.Popen(['mysql', '-u', username, '-p{}'.format(password), '-h', hostname, database], stdin=fd).wait()
```

You may want to tailor that a little as the password will be exposed to ps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming queries do end on line boundaries, you could just add lines together until they make a complete query.

Something like:

```
filename='/var/test.sql'
fp = open(filename)
lines = ''
while True:
        a = fp.readline()
        if not a:
           break
        try:
           cursor.execute(lines + a)
           lines = ''
        except e:
           lines += a
```

If it's only insert statements, you could look for lines ending ; and with the next line starting "INSERT".

```
filename='/var/test.sql'
fp = open(filename)
lines = ''
while True:
        a = fp.readline()
        if not a:
           break
        if lines.strip().endswith(';') and a.startswith('insert'):
           cursor.execute(lines)
           lines = a
        else:
           lines += a
# Catch the last one
cursor.execute(lines)
```

edit: replaced `trim()` with `strip()` & realised we don't need to execute the line `a` in second code example.

Comment: Thanks RJ. Good idea, I tried that but the dumps contain text that include semi-colons and newlines

Comment: @john machin @Xavier, yes, I meant strip. I wanted to take the newlines away before lines ended with ;. Unfortunately, python is not the language I've been programming with the most recently.

Comment: @JiminyCricket It has lines that end in ";" where the next line starts with "insert" *in the data*. What about the first method that just tries adding more lines to the query until it works?

Answer (score 0):

I think, sometimes, we should choose the other ways to do the job effectively. I prefer to use this stuff for large data: http://www.mysqldumper.net/